# Using a guid in google analytics userId field

Tags: google-analytics

Has anyone experience of setting the `userId` field in the tracking code as a `guid`?

I am trying but events are not being tracked. I tried with a random, shorter string and it worked. The [google api documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#userId) states there is no maxlength. I'm guessing there must be.

```
//var userId = 'dvdvddvdv'; // works
var userId = 'bee302e50ccc42f9a17ea5bb01125968'; // not works
ga('create', {
            trackingId: 'UA-XXXX-1',
            cookieDomain: 'auto',
            userId: userId
        });
```

**Update**

[Confirmed on Google support to be a bug](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=923)

Answer (score 1):

## No limits are explicitly defined

Google Documentation do not explicitly limit size of UserId.

## UUID v4

There is recomended scheme for User ID and it is called UUID v4 and it looks like:

> 6a14abda-6b12-4578-bf66-43c754eaeda9

This is 36 bytes long string.

Your tested string is 32 long, so this can not be problem.

> bee302e50ccc42f9a17ea5bb01125968

## Validating server

I either set up tracker as you described and test it on MP debug address:
From https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect

### Testing setup:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics_debug.js','ga');

var userId = 'bee302e50ccc42f9a17ea5bb01125968'; // not works
ga('create', {
    trackingId: 'UA-XXXX-Y',
    cookieDomain: 'auto',
    userId: userId  
});
ga('send', "pageview");
```

### Validating server response:

```
{
    "hitParsingResult": [{
        "valid": true,
        "parserMessage": [],
        "hit": "/debug/collect?tid=fake\u0026v=1\u0026_v=j41d\u0026a=1592400204\u0026t=pageview\u0026_s=2\u0026dl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fgtm%2Fga_cid.html\u0026ul=en-us\u0026de=UTF-8\u0026dt=SClient%20ID%20Experiment\u0026sd=24-bit\u0026sr=1920x1080\u0026vp=1920x946\u0026je=1\u0026cid=757970722.1459799458\u0026
uid=bee302e50ccc42f9a17ea5bb01125968
\u0026tid=UA-XXXXXX-6\u0026z=26198534"
    }],
    "parserMessage": [{
        "messageType": "INFO",
        "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
    }]
}
```

Comment: but apparently not by Google 3rd-line support ... https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=923 . Did you look in analytics reports though, on a user-tracking view? Nothing shows up...whilst an admiral post, all you've done there is confirm the request was handled.

Comment: Let me know when they solve it, I am interested in why this is not working on your side.